# How to include typed.js library in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, typed.js

I am trying to do some typed.js animation on chrome extension UI design. I have included a background.js, and I would love to execute a typing animation on my index.html which is the default popup stated in manifest.json.

However, after I have downloaded the typed.js and put all the src files into the extension folder. When I tried to load unpacked and ran it, the error log showed me all about the Unexpected tokens errors.

```
import { initializer } from 'initializer.js';
```

(The above line is highlighted as error on the extension management error log)

This is a line from typed.js library itself. What can I do about it?

Anyone please enlighten me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you need to use the single-file bundle from `lib/` folder.

Comment: Oh my god .. ok I have tried it. Now the problem is solved. But, there is a new one. In my background.js, I import from typed.js, this import line of code is flagged and said to have unexpected identifier..

Comment: Not sure why you're using a visual library in a hidden background script. If you include background.js in the popup, think twice: either rename the script to avoid the ambiguity or rework the architecture of your extension so that you don't include the script in two pages (the bg page and the popup page). Also, I think you don't need to import it - simply load it via a script tag in popup.html.

Comment: Thanks! Solved!